# Database connection setup broken after updating to Peewee 2.6 from 2.4

Tags: python, peewee

I want to upgrade Pewee from v2.4.7 to v2.6.3 in order to use the get_or_create method. However, after updating my connection setup is broken.

I used the following superclass to enable Foreign Key contraints with SQLite (2.6.3):

```
class SqliteFKDatabase(SqliteDatabase):                                                                                                                                              
    def initialize_connection(self):                                                                                                                                                 
        self.execute_sql('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;')                                                                                                                                  
        return self
```

... using the following connection setup code:

```
db = SqliteFKDatabase(None)  
init_db(path_to_db)   
def init_db(path_to_db):                                                                                                                                                        
    db.init(path_to_db)                                                                                                                                                                      
    db.connect()                                                                                                                                                                     
    db.initialize_connection()
```

However, when I run this code with the new version of Peewee I get the following error:

```
 File "./script.py", line 40, in init_db
    db.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3130, in connect
    self.initialize_connection(self.__local.conn)
TypeError: initialize_connection() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am only aware of passing *self* to *initialize_connection()*, so can anybody help me find what the second argument might me, and how to fix this bug?

**EDIT**

 Changing the class declaration method fixes the error.

```
    class SqliteFKDatabase(SqliteDatabase):                                                                                                                                              
        def initialize_connection(self, conn):                                                                                                                                           
            self.execute_sql('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;')
```

Answer (score 0):

`initialize_connection` takes a parameter, the newly-created `Connection` object.

This should work:

```
class SqliteFKDatabase(SqliteDatabase):                                                                                                                                              
    def initialize_connection(self, conn):                                                                                                                                                 
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;')
```

And your `init_db` does not need to call `initialize_connection` -- that is handled by Peewee:

```
def init_db(path_to_db):                                                                                                                                                        
    db.init(path_to_db)                                                                                                                                                                      
    db.connect()
```

Comment: in initialize_connection(), where is the Connection object conn coming from?

Comment: Anyways, now I get the following error :(   `File "./script.py", line 40, in init_db
    db.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3130, in connect
    self.initialize_connection(self.__local.conn)
  File "/Users/benjamin/Code/models.py", line 7, in initialize_connection
    cursor('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;')
TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not callable`

Comment: I haven't been able to find relevant documentation. Do you have some updated docs?

Comment: Sorry updated my comment, it should be `cursor.execute()`.